# How to insert a new line into the text file for Blackberry using OutputStream?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I am trying to create an application that is able to write text into text file in Blackberry. I am able to write text inside the text file, but when I try to write a new line of text, it just overwrites the text I write into previously. Can anyone help me? I try to look for the forums around but no one has the specific solution that I needed.

Below is my code:

```
package filepackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection;

import net.rim.device.api.io.File;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;

public class WritingText extends Application{
    /**
     * Entry point for application
     * @param args Command line arguments (not used)
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args){

        WritingText app = new WritingText();
        app.setAcceptEvents(false);

        Vector v = new Vector();
        v.addElement("Test2seconds.mp3");
        v.addElement("Test2seconds2.mp3");
        v.addElement("Test2seconds3.mp3");
        v.addElement("Test2seconds4.mp3");
        v.addElement("blind_willie.mp3");

        for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
        try 
        {
          FileConnection fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///SDCard/newfile.txt");
          // If no exception is thrown, then the URI is valid, but the file may or may not exist.
          if (!fc.exists())
          {
              fc.create();  // create the file if it doesn't exist
          }
          OutputStream outStream = fc.openOutputStream(); 
          outStream.write(((String) v.elementAt(i)).getBytes());

          String br = "\r\n";
          outStream.write (br.getBytes ());

          outStream.close();
          fc.close();
         }
         catch (IOException ioe) 
         {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage() );
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Please help me. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're creating a new file for each item in the vector. Try moving in the loop to surround only the write-operations:

```
.----
|     try 
|     {
|       FileConnection fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open(...);
|      // If no exception is thrown, then the URI is valid
|      if (!fc.exists())
|      {
|          fc.create();  // create the file if it doesn't exist
|      }
|      OutputStream outStream = fc.openOutputStream(); 
|
'-->  for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){

      outStream.write(((String) v.elementAt(i)).getBytes());

      String br = "\r\n";
      outStream.write (br.getBytes ());
.--> }
|
|      outStream.close();
|      fc.close();
|     }
|     catch (IOException ioe) 
|     {
|        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage() );
|     }
|   }
'--
```